# PHP headers_list() is not showing all headers

Tags: php, list, header, status

According to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php, and this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php#110330, php code:

```
<?php var_dump(header_list()); ?>
```

**Does not show the status headers.**

---

*This strange behavior is strange*.  So there are two questions:

1. **Why?** (I'm not sure if this question is opinion based, if it is, and there is no REAL explanation please omit it. I mean that sometimes opinion based questions aren't opinion based, and really have explanation, and this cannot be predict before they are asked).
2. I know that I can use my own function to set header, which will set header and additionally remember that this header was set. But this is kind of... workaround, as header_list() is quite sure **HERE, FOR THAT**. Additionally those headers are somewhere in the php engine memory so saving them second time inside script is not memory efficient. So... **What is the back-door to get all headers, not as stupid as workaround below?** This can be useful for example as a part of debug / developer class that is rendering all the "developer" data as html comments at the end of the page. *Of course I'm omitting the content length header which is too soon to predict.*
3. **It looks like this function omit all the headers that don't have colon... Is it right?**

---

To post more code, simple workaround to header function (linear not object, using globals and not static class just to show the idea). With the assumption that header function is omitting headers without colons (which may not be quite true...):

```
<?php
    // Mechanism:
    $headers = array();
    function setHeader($header) {
        header($header);
        if (strpos($header, ':') === false) {
            global $headers;
            $headers[] = $header;
        }
    }
    function getHeaders() {
        global $headers;
        return array_merge($headers, header_list());
    }

    // Example:
    setHeader('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    var_dump(getHeaders());
?>
```

Comment: I don't see how the function should know about the http status before anything has been attempted to send. In general I would expect that the function lists all headers prepared by php. Since the http protocol itself is _not_ handled by php but by the underlying http server, how should php know about that? I do agree that this might be inconvenient. But I do not see a technical solution for this.

Comment: Yeah, but when You set header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); it is quite obvious, that the status code will be 404...? And if You overwrite it with 403, it will be 403...? I mean that You are directly setting the status using header, so why this header is not on the list? What more, when you set encoding, or something else, it is on the list... Only status headers and non colon headers are not on the list :(.

Comment: I would assume that such header is _not_ directly queued inside php out of exactly the same reasons. The final http status can only be set by the http server. So probably the headers are handled differently. Headers listed by that function are queued inside php, request protocol related headers are probably somehow signaled inside the inter process communication between http server and php. Like a "return value".

Comment: OK, I quite get it. Feel free to post answer with some more informations, resources or documentation of that issue, and I will of course accept it. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: No, thanks: I am just expressing my judgement here. This is nothing I know. So it is not an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [engine source for `headers_list` and `http_response_code`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/ext/standard/head.c#L297-L341), notice that the value for general headers and status code are separated:

```
// headers_list
SG(sapi_headers).headers

// http_response_code
SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code
```

But HTTP response code isn't the only header with dedicated storage: [Content-Type does, too](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/main/SAPI.c#L405):

```
SG(sapi_headers).mimetype = NULL;
```

So what's going on here? The [complete header() algorithm](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/main/SAPI.c#L659-L842) specifically checks for the following strings to adjust state:

- `HTTP/`
- `Content-Type`
- `Content-Length`
- `Location`
- `WWW-Authenticate`

`HTTP/` is checked specifically because that's how one set the status code explicitly before PHP 5.4: after that, [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) is available and is recommended for clarity. That `header()` was used is confusing, for the reason you're asking in this question and on general principle: the [http header BNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) clearly doesn't include status line:

> ```
> header-field   = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS
> ```

PHP handles the others separately because they are single-value headers and/or their value matters for efficiency in later calculations.

TL;DR: `HTTP/` set by `header()` isn't included in `headers_list()` because `HTTP/` status lines are not headers in the strict RFC sense. But for the PHP < 5.4 limitation that `header()` was the *only way to set* `HTTP/` status, it'd likely have never been a confusing issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that only the status code is missing from the `header_list`.

You can get the current status code (they probably overwrite one another) using another function: [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php).