# how to fetch the value if we know the key in php

Tags: php, key-value

I have designed a code which goes through each line and extracts particular string using position of the the string. However I don't want it a hard coded way. How can I use the key-value pair for my code. In my case file pattern is fixed. For example:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35

Content-Length: 17

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive
```

In this "X-Powered-By" is the key & "PHP/5.6.35" is the value.

```
<pre><?php
$array = array();
$val = array();
//$vals = array();
    $fh = fopen("website-audit.2018.08.30.log","r");
    $started = false;
    while (!feof($fh)) {
      $line = fgets($fh);
      if($started) {
        $temp .= $line;
        if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-Z-") > 0) {
          $started = false;
          $array[] = $temp;
        }
      }
      if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-A-") > 0) {
        $started = true;
        $temp = $line;
      }
    }
    fclose($fh);

    $keyword = 'POST';

    foreach($array as $index){
        if (strpos($index, $keyword) !== FALSE){
            $val[] = $index;
    }   
}
var_dump($val);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); ++$i) {

        $words = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $val[$i]);

            $X_REQUESTED_WITH = explode(' ',trim($words[9]));
            $X_REQUESTED_WITH = $X_REQUESTED_WITH[1] . PHP_EOL;

            $RESPONSE_CODE = explode(' ',trim($words[22]));
            $RESPONSE_CODE = $RESPONSE_CODE[1] . PHP_EOL;

            echo $X_REQUESTED_WITH;
            echo $RESPONSE_CODE;
        }           
?>
```

Output of this code :

```html
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(898) "--84670001-A--
[31/Aug/2018:13:41:25 +0200] W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8 127.0.0.1 55065 127.0.0.1 80
--84670001-B--
POST /FormValidation/validation.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
cookie: authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/page1.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

--84670001-C--
name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
--84670000-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 17
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--84670001-Z--
"
  [1]=>
  string(897) "--84670002-A--
[31/Aug/2018:13:41:25 +0200] W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8 127.0.0.1 55065 127.0.0.1 80
--84670002-B--
POST /FormValidation/validation.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
cookie: authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/page1.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

--84670002-C--
name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
--84670002-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 17
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--84670002-Z--"
}

XMLHttpRequest
200

XMLHttpRequest
200
```

This is my file :-

```
--49160000-A--
[30/Aug/2018:13:41:19 +0200] W4fX34HC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOgAAAD4 127.0.0.1 55064 127.0.0.1 80
--49160000-B--
GET /FormValidation/page1.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343

--49160000-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 851
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--49160000-Z--

--84670001-A--
[31/Aug/2018:13:41:25 +0200] W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8 127.0.0.1 55065 127.0.0.1 80
--84670001-B--
POST /FormValidation/validation.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
cookie: authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/page1.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

--84670001-C--
name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
--84670000-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 17
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--84670001-Z--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ligthly alter your current code to make it able to parse the file as you want.

Given a file  `website-audit.2018.08.30.log` with the following content:

```
--84670001-A--
[31/Aug/2018:13:41:25 +0200] W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8 127.0.0.1 55065 127.0.0.1 80
--84670001-B--
POST /FormValidation/validation.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
cookie: authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/page1.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

--84670001-C--
name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
--84670000-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 17
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--84670001-Z--
--84670002-A--
[31/Aug/2018:13:41:25 +0200] W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8 127.0.0.1 55065 127.0.0.1 80
--84670002-B--
POST /FormValidation/validation.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
cookie: authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/FormValidation/page1.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

--84670002-C--
name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
--84670002-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Content-Length: 17
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--84670002-Z--
```

this is an **Example of parser** you can build:

```
$fh = fopen("website-audit.2018.08.30.log","r");
    $array = array();
    $started = false;
    while (!feof($fh)) {
      $line = trim(fgets($fh));
      if($started) {


         if(!ctype_space($line)&&!empty($line)&&!preg_match('#-$#',$line)){
                if(strpos($line,'POST')===0){
                    $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                    $temp['POST']=array_slice($data,1,2);
                }
                else{
                    if(isset($A)){
                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                        $data[0].=$data[1];
                        unset($data[1]);
                        $temp['Stamp']=array_values($data);
                        unset($A);
                    }else{

                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,':',''));
                        if(isset($data[1])){
                            if($data[0]=='Keep-Alive'){
                                $d=explode(',',$data[1]);
                                $d[0]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[0]));
                                $d[1]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[1]));
                                $temp[$data[0]]=[$d[0][0]=>$d[0][1],$d[1][0]=>$d[1][1]];
                            }else{
                                $temp[$data[0]]=$data[1];
                            }
                        }elseif(strpos($data[0],'HTTP')===0){
                            $data=explode(' ',$data[0]);
                            $temp['HTTP']=array_combine(['version','status','message'],$data);
                        }else{
                            $temp['Query_string']=$data[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
         }


        if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-Z-") > 0) {
            $started = false;
            $array[$tmp] = $temp;
            $temp=[];
            $tmp++;
        }
      }
      if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-A-") > 0) {
        $A=true;
        $started = true;
        $tmp=trim($line);
        $temp=[];
      }
    }
    fclose($fh);
//from there $array contains as needed Pair of key=>$value for each request then you can use
foreach($array as $k=>$value){
    var_dump($value['X-Requested-With']);
    var_dump($value['HTTP']['status']);
}
```

To output:

```
string(14) "XMLHttpRequest"
string(3) "200"
string(14) "XMLHttpRequest"
string(3) "200"
```

and the full content of the variable $array is:

```
Array
(
    [--84670001-A--] => Array
        (
            [Stamp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [31/Aug/2018:13:41:25+0200]
                    [1] => W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8
                    [2] => 127.0.0.1
                    [3] => 55065
                    [4] => 127.0.0.1
                    [5] => 80
                )

            [POST] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /FormValidation/validation.php
                    [1] => HTTP/1.1
                )

            [Host] => localhost
            [Connection] => Keep-Alive
            [Content-Length] => 17
            [Accept] => */*
            [Origin] => http
            [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
            [cookie] => authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
            [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
            [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [Referer] => http
            [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
            [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9
            [tanuser] => 00198343
            [env] => dev
            [Query_string] => name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
            [HTTP] => Array
                (
                    [version] => HTTP/1.1
                    [status] => 200
                    [message] => OK
                )

            [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.6.35
            [Keep-Alive] => Array
                (
                    [timeout] => 5
                    [max] => 100
                )

        )

    [--84670002-A--] => Array
        (
            [Stamp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [31/Aug/2018:13:41:25+0200]
                    [1] => W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8
                    [2] => 127.0.0.1
                    [3] => 55065
                    [4] => 127.0.0.1
                    [5] => 80
                )

            [POST] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /FormValidation/validation.php
                    [1] => HTTP/1.1
                )

            [Host] => localhost
            [Connection] => Keep-Alive
            [Content-Length] => 17
            [Accept] => */*
            [Origin] => http
            [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
            [cookie] => authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
            [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
            [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [Referer] => http
            [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
            [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9
            [tanuser] => 00198343
            [env] => dev
            [Query_string] => name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
            [HTTP] => Array
                (
                    [version] => HTTP/1.1
                    [status] => 200
                    [message] => OK
                )

            [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.6.35
            [Keep-Alive] => Array
                (
                    [timeout] => 5
                    [max] => 100
                )

        )

)
```

So as you may see it is really easy and it works fine.
Then if the content of your file changed a little so you need to just add a condition

example: for your current file

```
$fh = fopen("website-audit.2018.08.30.log","r");
    $array = array();
    $started = false;
    while (!feof($fh)) {
      $line = trim(fgets($fh));
      if($started) {


         if(!ctype_space($line)&&!empty($line)&&!preg_match('#-$#',$line)){
                if(strpos($line,'POST')===0){
                    $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                    $temp['POST']=array_slice($data,1,2);
                }
                elseif(strpos($line,'GET')===0){
                    $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                    $temp['GET']=array_slice($data,1,2);
                }
                else{
                    if(isset($A)){
                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,' ',''));
                        $data[0].=$data[1];
                        unset($data[1]);
                        $temp['Stamp']=array_values($data);
                        unset($A);
                    }else{

                        $data=array_map('trim',str_getcsv($line,':',''));
                        if(isset($data[1])){
                            if($data[0]=='Keep-Alive'){
                                $d=explode(',',$data[1]);
                                $d[0]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[0]));
                                $d[1]=array_map('trim',explode('=',$d[1]));
                                $temp[$data[0]]=[$d[0][0]=>$d[0][1],$d[1][0]=>$d[1][1]];
                            }else{
                                $temp[$data[0]]=$data[1];
                            }
                        }elseif(strpos($data[0],'HTTP')===0){
                            $data=explode(' ',$data[0]);
                            $temp['HTTP']=array_combine(['version','status','message'],$data);
                        }else{
                            $temp['Query_string']=$data[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
         }


        if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-Z-") > 0) {
            $started = false;
            $array[$tmp] = $temp;
            $temp=[];
            $tmp++;
        }
      }
      if(strpos($line, "--") === 0 && strpos($line, "-A-") > 0) {
        $A=true;
        $started = true;
        $tmp=trim($line);
        $temp=[];
      }
    }
    fclose($fh);

print_r($array);
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [--49160000-A--] => Array
        (
            [Stamp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [30/Aug/2018:13:41:19+0200]
                    [1] => W4fX34HC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOgAAAD4
                    [2] => 127.0.0.1
                    [3] => 55064
                    [4] => 127.0.0.1
                    [5] => 80
                )

            [GET] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /FormValidation/page1.php
                    [1] => HTTP/1.1
                )

            [Host] => localhost
            [Connection] => Keep-Alive
            [Upgrade-Insecure-Requests] => 1
            [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
            [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
            [Referer] => http
            [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
            [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9
            [tanuser] => 00198343
            [HTTP] => Array
                (
                    [version] => HTTP/1.1
                    [status] => 200
                    [message] => OK
                )

            [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.6.35
            [Content-Length] => 851
            [Keep-Alive] => Array
                (
                    [timeout] => 5
                    [max] => 99
                )

            [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [--84670001-A--] => Array
        (
            [Stamp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [31/Aug/2018:13:41:25+0200]
                    [1] => W4fX5YHC0Xb8YDuIqk5YOwAAAD8
                    [2] => 127.0.0.1
                    [3] => 55065
                    [4] => 127.0.0.1
                    [5] => 80
                )

            [POST] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /FormValidation/validation.php
                    [1] => HTTP/1.1
                )

            [Host] => localhost
            [Connection] => Keep-Alive
            [Content-Length] => 17
            [Accept] => */*
            [Origin] => http
            [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
            [cookie] => authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg
            [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
            [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [Referer] => http
            [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
            [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9
            [tanuser] => 00198343
            [env] => dev
            [Query_string] => name1=test&email1=ssn%40gmail.com
            [HTTP] => Array
                (
                    [version] => HTTP/1.1
                    [status] => 200
                    [message] => OK
                )

            [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.6.35
            [Keep-Alive] => Array
                (
                    [timeout] => 5
                    [max] => 100
                )

        )

)
```

So if you just need the GET request you check in the loop if index GET exists for the current element :
example:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$value){
    if(isset($value["POST"])){
        var_dump($value['X-Requested-With']);
        var_dump($value['HTTP']['status']);
    }elseif(isset($value["GET"])){
        var_dump($value['tanuser']);
        var_dump($value['HTTP']['status']);
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
string(8) "00198343"
string(3) "200"
string(14) "XMLHttpRequest"
string(3) "200"
```

Comment: Thanks much. Actually i have a file which holds both GET & POST data. I want only POST data. However when i am running your code it is returning me all the data related to this tag( Example- two tanusers, two X-Requested-With, two status)

Comment: See this is my output:-

NULL

string(3) "200"

string(8) "00198343"

NULL

string(0) ""

string(0) ""

string(3) "851"

NULL

string(14) "XMLHttpRequest"

string(3) "200"

string(8) "00198343"

string(30) "authscheme=abc;authMarket=abfg"

string(3) "abc"

string(4) "abfg"

string(2) "17"

string(3) "dev"

Comment: I  build my code  only based on the output in your question.If your file contains more data, you need to edit your question to show the full content.

Comment: I edited the answer.Don't forget to mark your question as solved once the answer tested...

Comment: Also keep in mind that the parser necessarily returns all the request occurences with their respective ID as index as you may see in my answer.You can use a loop or specify an ID as index to get its content if you just need a specific request...

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a header response every time, you could use [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php), it will return an associative array of all the HTTP headers in the current request

```
<?php

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't want all the headers. I just want specific header values. Example: tanuser: 00198343
env: dev

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to get particular header value using key. example:

```
 echo getallheaders()['Accept-Encoding']; 

 echo getallheaders()['X-Powered-By'];
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do that? getallheaders() doesnot return all the headers i want.

Comment: `getallheaders()` will return the request headers and is therefore not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555392/php-headers-list-is-not-showing-all-headers?answertab=votes#tab-top